# Check if user is asked for a password during ssh

Tags: python, ssh, passwords, sftp

I want to know if there's a way in Python that I can detect if a user is asked for a password when connecting to sftp using ssh, then is able to ignore connecting?

Thanks.

Comment: Too vague - please provide add'l details.  Have you attempted to write this already? If so, please provide sample code.  If not, check out the [paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/) documentation (assuming you're using [paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/)) and try hacking out some code to do what you want it to do, then post it if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware that such thing is possible with python; anyway I wouldn't recommend anything involving checking for password interactive prompts even if probably you could try to filter the subprocess pipes (in case you are calling sftp with Popen).

If your goal is to prevent password authentication you may call sftp with the `PasswordAuthentication=no` and `PreferredAuthentications=publickey` like this:

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey host
```

In this way it should fail if a password is required.